# Max gap size for effective drywall joint compound

Tags: drywall, joints

I am getting ready to mesh tape and apply joint compound to my drywall patch but I am wondering if my replacement piece is not snug enough. After doing a bunch of adjustments and trying to cut for my replacement piece, I wound up taking just a bit too much....
I've read up to a gap inch is fine and at its widest point, my install is just over 1/2" but I would just like to make sure.

**WARNING: NOVICE GORE**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll be fine, though you might want to go buy a bag of setting type (dry powder, mix with water - sets, rather than drying out like the stuff in a bucket) joint compound, both because [it's the right type for use with mesh tape](http://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/drywall-finishing-technical-guide-en-J1990.pdf), and becasue of this tid-bit from USG:

> Open spaces between panels of 6.4 mm (1/4) or more should be filled with compound at least 24 hours prior to embedding or first-coat work. Setting-type joint compounds, which are hardening types, are recommended for these large fills. With these setting-type compounds as a fill, joint treatment may begin as soon as the compound has hardened, eliminating the typical 24-hr. drying period.

From this document: http://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/canada/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/cgc-construction-handbook-ch5-finishing-drywall-systems-can-en-pdf.pdf

As the real 'rockers say, mud covers a lot of sins...or gore.

Comment: +1 Also the OP may want to try to make sure that the patch is fairly level with the surrounding wall. The edge on the left of the picture looks a little low. A thin shim behind the patch could be used to level.

Comment: +1 to the answer. Very interesting subtleties about matching mud and tape.

Comment: Watch what you shim with. It isn't so low that you can't just float some mud in there and fill it.

Comment: +1 - You may also want to scrape that texture down a bit, before you start - it will make it hard, to get a smooth seam at first.